# in objective-c how to programmatically expand the size of cells according to the UICollection frame size when rotating the device?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In objective-c, my cells don't expand their widths according to `UICollection` frame size when the device is rotated.

I can not use constraints on cells but just labels and buttons. So how do I add constraints to cells programmatically to auto layout the width according to `UICollection` frame size?

Answer (score 0):

You could use that kind of method :

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) 
                                            {
                                                self.layoutWidth = size.width;
                                                //Do any setup you need here
                                            }
            completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
                            {
                            }];
}
```

I might not be right but you can also try in your xib file to tick "autoresize subviews" on your collectionView.

Hope it was usefull, do not hesitate to edit/correct my answer if you think I'm wrong.

Comment: Well, sorry for that. I do not have any other idea yet...
It might not be your case but, did you reload the data properly after changing the sizes ? Using `[self.collectionView reloadData]` .